# Laptop makes loud noise when an external display is connected

Tags: laptop, external-display, noise

I've a MSI GS63VR 7RF laptop with a GTX 1070, and suddenly it has started making a loud noise that resembles the noise that printers make while printing some document.

It seems that when I disconnect the secondary monitor this noise stops.

I've been searching without any result, because I found GPU coil whine, but seems to be a different issue.

Also I read about disabling vsync, but doing so didn't affect the noise.

What can be this issue and how to solve it?

Comment: Check the fan of your graphic card, when a second monitor is connected more power is used and the fan starts spinning (often on desktop fan stops as not required) => hardware error

Comment: Connecting an external monitor might switch on the discrete graphics card in your laptop, which in turn might cause a fan to start spinning. That fan might be obstructed by some dust or other particles or might be on its way out. This seems the most likely case to me.

Comment: Could you add a recording of the noise? It would be way more helpful than a personal interpretation of the noise written down in text.